# Recursive type synonym with promoted constructors

Tags: haskell, data-kinds, recursive-type

I have a nice way to wrap multiple type parameters into one.

```hs
data WorldModel = WorldModel Type Type Type
-- plus type families to extract them
```

I ha**d** a type synonym `type PlainWorldModel = 'WorldModel Some Instantiation Here` which works fine.

Now I want the parameterisation to be recursive
`type PlainWorldModel = 'WorldModel Some Instantiation (Here PlainWorldModel)` which I cannot obviously do with type synonyms, because of substitution.

How can I do it with newtype? I can't make the newtyped field be of type `WorldModel`, only of `Type`.

Do I need to bring in `singletons`?

Concisely,

```hs
type PlainWorldModel = 'WorldModel Some Instantiation Here -- this was fine
type PlainWorldModel = 'WorldModel Some Instantiation (HereParameterised PlainWorldModel) -- I want to do this and it is not fine

newtype PlainWorldModel = PWM ( 'WorldModel Some Instantiation (HereParameterised PlainWorldModel)) -- this does not work
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a definite answer, but I am leaning towards this being impossible to achieve in Haskell.

A key feature of types in Haskell is that whenever we have `t :: k` where `k` is any kind, then the (type-level) expression `t` should be (strongly) normalizing. In other words we should be able to expand all type synonyms, all type families, etc. in `t` and reach its normal form in a finite number of steps.

There are a few culprits here that partially break this property. `UndecidableInstances` for instance allows for infinitely recursing type families. Having `Type :: Type` is also problematic. However, if we disregard those, normalization should hold.

Now, what you want to achieve is general type-level recursion `type T = F T` for some `F`. This is called "equi-recursion" and would break normalization and arguably should be prevented at all kinds.

You might then wonder why in the kind `Type` we do allow recursion, then. Well, there we only allow "iso-recursion". We never have the strict equality `T ~ F T` but we only allow the two distinct types `T` and `F T` which "just happen" to be isomorphic, and provide the constructors/eliminators to express such isomorphism. This also makes our type system nominal (and not structural).

Such recursion only happens at the kind `Type` though.

My hunch is that, if we wanted to allow recursion in other kinds, we would need to have some form of "iso-recursion", so to ensure normalization. I am not completely sure about how that would work.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it sounds like a correct solution to my original question, thank you :) I have found a workaround, at least.

Answer (score 2):

So whilst chi's answer is the correct answer to the question, in my *specific* case I was able to fix this by redefining `WorldModel`

`data WorldModel = WorldModel Type Type (WorldModel -> Type)`

In the type family I *can* recurse explicitly:

```hs
type family WMHere (wm :: WorldModel) :: Type where
  WMHere ('WorldModel some instantiation here) = a ('WorldModel some instantiation here)
```

now, I can make my type synonym `type PlainWorldModel = 'WorldModel Some Instantiation Here` and it works.

Of course this is more "due to the details of what I was doing, there is a workaround" rather than an answer to the question as a whole.